# MySQL and MS SQL query execution differs

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```
 SELECT ACOS(31.552278760192)
```

when executed in MSSQL Server it returns some value but when executed in MYSQL it returns null.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do not you check what ACOS(SIN(31.552278760192) * SIN(latitute) + COS(31.552278760192) * 
 COS(latitute) * COS(longitute) - 74.338372290294) * 
 6371 is returning on mySQL? There might be some issue there.

Comment: Agreed - you need to break down each selection.

Comment: @Kangkan, I am not so lazy. I have checked it. It is returning something which is not null.

Comment: @Kangkan, I have edited the original post kindly read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_acos):

> `ACOS(X)`
>   Returns the arc cosine of X, that is, the value whose cosine is X. Returns NULL if X is not in the range -1 to 1.

So 31.552278760192 is out of range for MySQL's `ACOS`. In fact, the arccosine function doesn't produce a real number as a result outside of `[-1,1]` and [`acos(31.552278760192)` is ~4i](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acos%2831.552278760192%29).

Comment: Great grand reply. Such a deep insight. Where is the +10 up vote button?